# Duplicates removal in urls list

Tags: selenium, url, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I would appreciate assistance with the following.
I'm scraping data from amazon Laptops product info. I have obtained the URLs and put them into a  list using the following code

```
urls_list=[]
import numpy as np
from collections import OrderedDict 
pages = np.arange(0,4)
for page in pages:
    time.sleep(3)
    page=driver.get('https://www.amazon.com/s?k=laptops&page='+str(page)+'&qid=1611094287&ref=sr_pg_')
    base_url='https://www.amazon.com/'
    sleep(randint(2,3))
    soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    las=soup.find_all('h2',class_="a-size-mini a-spacing-none a-color-base s-line-clamp-2")
    base_url='https://www.amazon.com/'
for s in las:
    last= s.find_all('a',href=True)
    for links in last:
        #print(links['href'])
        was=links['href']
        was=was.replace('https:/','')
        base=(base_url+was)
        urls_list.append(base)
        print(urls_list)
```

it returns a list of URLs that has a lot of duplicates. I would like assistance on how I would get the URLs I need without them getting duplicated. calling the len returns, 357 URLs instead of 66

```
    'https://www.amazon.com//gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_atf_next_aps_sr_pg4_1?ie=UTF8&adId=A00982583SKT9G1E8WEMD&url=%2FHigh-Performance-Ultra-Thin-Entertainment-pre-Installed-Professional%2Fdp%2FB079GQK6BC%2Fref%3Dsr_1_49_sspa%3Fdchild%3D1%26keywords%3Dlaptops%26qid%3D1611094287%26sr%3D8-49-spons%26psc%3D1&qualifier=1611274529&id=2949216330232123&widgetName=sp_atf_next']
['https://www.amazon.com//gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_atf_next_aps_sr_pg4_1?ie=UTF8&adId=A00982583SKT9G1E8WEMD&url=%2FHigh-Performance-Ultra-Thin-Entertainment-pre-Installed-Professional%2Fdp%2FB079GQK6BC%2Fref%3Dsr_1_49_sspa%3Fdchild%3D1%26keywords%3Dlaptops%26qid%3D1611094287%26sr%3D8-49-spons%26psc%3D1&qualifier=1611274529&id=2949216330232123&widgetName=sp_atf_next', 'https://www.amazon.com//gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_atf_next_aps_sr_pg4_1?ie=UTF8&adId=A01913892JJI6KO2E97JD&url=%2FStationaryLab-Aluminum-Organizer-Adjustable-Compatible%2Fdp%2FB08P38JJV8%2Fref%3Dsr_1_50_sspa%3Fdchild%3D1%26keywords%3Dlaptops%26qid%3D1611094287%26sr%3D8-50-spons%26psc%3D1&qualifier=1611274529&id=2949216330232123&widgetName=sp_atf_next']
['https://www.amazon.com//gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_atf_next_aps_sr_pg4_1?ie=UTF8&adId=A00982583SKT9G1E8WEMD&url=%2FHigh-Performance-Ultra-Thin-Entertainment-pre-Installed-Professional%2Fdp%2FB079GQK6BC%2Fref%3Dsr_1_49_sspa%3Fdchild%3D1%26keywords%3Dlaptops%26qid%3D1611094287%26sr%3D8-49-spons%26psc%3D1&qualifier=1611274529&id=2949216330232123&widgetName=sp_atf_next', 'https://www.amazon.com//gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_atf_next_aps_sr_pg4_1?ie=UTF8&adId=A01913892JJI6KO2E97JD&url=%2FStationaryLab-Aluminum-Organizer-Adjustable-Compatible%2Fdp%2FB08P38JJV8%2Fref%3Dsr_1_50_sspa%3Fdchild%3D1%26keywords%3Dlaptops%26qid%3D1611094287%26sr%3D8-50-spons%26psc%3D1&qualifier=1611274529&id=2949216330232123&widgetName=sp_atf_next', 'https://www.amazon.com//HP-Touchscreen-Dual-Core-Processor-14-ds0110nr/dp/B07RX2XV4N/ref=sr_1_51?dchild=1&keywords=laptops&qid=1611094287&sr=8-51']
['https://www.amazon.com//gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_atf_next_aps_sr_pg4_1?ie=UTF8&adId=A00982583SKT9G1E8WEMD&url=%2FHigh-Performance-Ultra-Thin-Entertainment-pre-Installed-Professional%2Fdp%2FB079GQK6BC%2Fref%3Dsr_1_49_sspa%3Fdchild%3D1%26keywords%3Dlaptops%26qid%3D1611094287%26sr%3D8-49-spons%26psc%3D1&qualifier=1611274529&id=2949216330232123&widgetName=sp_atf_next', 'https://www.amazon.com//gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_atf_next_aps_sr_pg4_1?ie=UTF8&adId=A01913892JJI6KO2E97JD&url=%2FStationaryLab-Aluminum-Organizer-Adjustable-Compatible%2Fdp%2FB08P38JJV8%2Fref%3Dsr_1_50_sspa%3Fdchild%3D1%26keywords%3Dlaptops%26qid%3D1611094287%26sr%3D8-50-spons%26psc%3D1&qualifier=1611274529&id=2949216330232123&widgetName=sp_atf_next', 'https://www.amazon.com//HP-Touchscreen-Dual-Core-Processor-14-ds0110nr/dp/B07RX2XV4N/ref=sr_1_51?dchild=1&keywords=laptops&qid=1611094287&sr=8-51', 'https://www.amazon.com//Traditional-Computers-Supports-Expansion-Personal/dp/B08HRVCN8K/ref=sr_1_52?dchild=1&keywords=laptops&qid=1611094287&sr=8-52']
['https://www.amazon.com//gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_atf_next_aps_sr_pg4_1?ie=UTF8&adId=A00982583SKT9G1E8WEMD&url=%2FHigh-Performance-Ultra-Thin-Entertainment-pre-Installed-Professional%2Fdp%2FB079GQK6BC%2Fref%3Dsr_1_49_sspa%3Fdchild%3D1%26keywords%3Dlaptops%26qid%3D1611094287%26sr%3D8-49-spons%26psc%3D1&qualifier=1611274529&id=2949216330232123&widgetName=sp_atf_next', 'https://www.amazon.com//gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_atf_next_aps_sr_pg4_1?ie=UTF8&adId=A01913892JJI6KO2E97JD&url=%2FStationaryLab-Aluminum-Organizer-Adjustable-Compatible%2Fdp%2FB08P38JJV8%2Fref%3Dsr_1_50_sspa%3Fdchild%3D1%26keywords%3Dlaptops%26qid%3D1611094287%26sr%3D8-50-spons%26psc%3D1&qualifier=1611274529&id=2949216330232123&widgetName=sp_atf_next', 'https://www.amazon.com//HP-Touchscreen-Dual-Core-Processor-14-ds0110nr/dp/B07RX2XV4N/ref=sr_1_51?dchild=1&keywords=laptops&qid=1611094287&sr=8-51', 'https://www.amazon.com//Traditional-Computers-Supports-Expansion-Personal/dp/B08HRVCN8K/ref=sr_1_52?dchild=1&keywords=laptops&qid=1611094287&sr=8-52', 'https://www.amazon.com//HP-Dual-Core-Processor-Bluetooth-Microsoft/dp/B08KLMKLZR/ref=sr_1_53?dchild=1&keywords=laptops&qid=1611094287&sr=8-53']
['https://www.amazon.com//gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_atf_next_aps_sr_pg4_1?ie=UTF8&adId=A00982583SKT9G1E8WEMD&url=%2FHigh-Performance-Ultra-Thin-Entertainment-pre-Installed-Professional%2Fdp%2FB079GQK6BC%2Fref%3Dsr_1_49_sspa%3Fdchild%3D1%26keywords%3Dlaptops%26qid%3D1611094287%26sr%3D8-49-spons%26psc%3D1&qualifier=1611274529&id=2949216330232123&widgetName=sp_atf_next', 'https://www.amazon.com//gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_atf_next_aps_sr_pg4_1?ie=UTF8&adId=A01913892JJI6KO2E97JD&url=%2FStationaryLab-Aluminum-Organizer-Adjustable-Compatible%2Fdp%2FB08P38JJV8%2Fref%3Dsr_1_50_sspa%3Fdchild%3D1%26keywords%3Dlaptops%26qid%3D1611094287%26sr%3D8-50-spons%26psc%3D1&qualifier=1611274529&id=2949216330232123&widgetName=sp_atf_next', 'https://www.amazon.com//HP-Touchscreen-Dual-Core-Processor-14-ds0110nr/dp/B07RX2XV4N/ref=sr_1_51?dchild=1&keywords=laptops&qid=1611094287&sr=8-51', 'https://www.amazon.com//Traditional-Computers-Supports-Expansion-Personal/dp/B08HRVCN8K/ref=sr_1_52?dchild=1&keywords=laptops&qid=1611094287&sr=8-52', 'https://www.amazon.com//HP-Dual-Core-Processor-Bluetooth-Microsoft/dp/B08KLMKLZR/ref=sr_1_53?dchild=1&keywords=laptops&qid=1611094287&sr=8-53', 'https://www.amazon.com//HP-Stream-Laptop-Intel-Renewed/dp/B08LDLRNGF/ref=sr_1_54?dchild=1&keywords=laptops&qid=1611094287&sr=8-54']
['https://www.amazon.com//gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_atf_next_aps_sr_pg4_1?ie=UTF8&adId=A00982583SKT9G1E8WEMD&url=%2FHigh-Performance-Ultra-Thin-Entertainment-pre-Installed-Professional%2Fdp%2FB079GQK6BC%2Fref%3Dsr_1_49_sspa%3Fdchild%3D1%26keywords%3Dlaptops%26qid%3D1611094287%26sr%3D8-49-spons%26psc%3D1&qualifier=1611274529&id=2949216330232123&widgetName=sp_atf_next', 'https://www.amazon.com//gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_atf_next_aps_sr_pg4_1?ie=UTF8&adId=A01913892JJI6KO2E97JD&url=%2FStationaryLab-Aluminum-Organizer-Adjustable-Compatible%2Fdp%2FB08P38JJV8%2Fref%3Dsr_1_50_sspa%3Fdchild%3D1%26keywords%3Dlaptops%26qid%3D1611094287%26sr%3D8-50-spons%26psc%3D1&qualifier=1611274529&id=2949216330232123&widgetName=sp_atf_next', 'https://www.amazon.com//HP-Touchscreen-Dual-Core-Processor-14-ds0110nr/dp/B07RX2XV4N/ref=sr_1_51?dchild=1&keywords=laptops&qid=1611094287&sr=8-51', 'https://www.amazon.com//Traditional-Computers-Supports-Expansion-Personal/dp/B08HRVCN8K/ref=sr_1_52?dchild=1&keywords=laptops&qid=1611094287&sr=8-52', 'https://www.amazon.com//HP-Dual-Core-Processor-Bluetooth-Microsoft/dp/B08KLMKLZR/ref=sr_1_53?dchild=1&keywords=laptops&qid=1611094287&sr=8-53', 'https://www.amazon.com//HP-Stream-Laptop-Intel-Renewed/dp/B08LDLRNGF/ref=sr_1_54?dchild=1&keywords=laptops&qid=1611094287&sr=8-54', 'https://www.amazon.com//X3-Air-13-3-inch-180%C2%B0Rotation-Dual-band/dp/B087M2CQG6/ref=sr_1_55?dchild=1&keywords=laptops&qid=1611094287&sr=8-55']
['https://www.amazon.com//gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_atf_next_aps_sr_pg4_1?ie=UTF8&adId=A00982583SKT9G1E8WEMD&url=%2FHigh-Performance-Ultra-Thin-Entertainment-pre-Installed-Professional%2Fdp%2FB079GQK6BC%2Fref%3Dsr_1_49_sspa%3Fdchild%3D1%26keywords%3Dlaptops%26qid%3D1611094287%26sr%3D8-49-spons%26psc%3D1&qualifier=1611274529&id=2949216330232123&widgetName=sp_atf_next', 'https://www.amazon.com//gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_atf_next_aps_sr_pg4_1?ie=UTF8&adId=A01913892JJI6KO2E97JD&url=%2FStationaryLab-Aluminum-Organizer-Adjustable-Compatible%2Fdp%2FB08P38JJV8%2Fref%3Dsr_1_50_sspa%3Fdchild%3D1%26keywords%3Dlaptops%26qid%3D1611094287%26sr%3D8-50-spons%26psc%3D1&qualifier=1611274529&id=2949216330232123&widgetName=sp_atf_next', 'https://www.amazon.com//HP-Touchscreen-Dual-Core-Processor-14-ds0110nr/dp/B07RX2XV4N/ref=sr_1_51?dchild=1&keywords=laptops&qid=1611094287&sr=8-51', 'https://www.amazon.com//Traditional-Computers-Supports-Expansion-Personal/dp/B08HRVCN8K/ref=sr_1_52?dchild=1&keywords=laptops&qid=1611094287&sr=8-52', 'https://www.amazon.com//HP-Dual-Core-Processor-Bluetooth-Microsoft/dp/B08KLMKLZR/ref=sr_1_53?dchild=1&keywords=laptops&qid=1611094287&sr=8-53', 'https://www.amazon.com//HP-Stream-Laptop-Intel-Renewed/dp/B08LDLRNGF/ref=sr_1_54?dchild=1&keywords=laptops&qid=1611094287&sr=8-54', 'https://www.amazon.com//X3-Air-13-3-inch-180%C2%B0Rotation-Dual-band/dp/B087M2CQG6/ref=sr_1_55?dchild=1&keywords=laptops&qid=1611094287&sr=8-55', 'https://www.amazon.com//HP-i5-10210U-i7-8665U-Keyboard-Graphics/dp/B08QNGWYLJ/ref=sr_1_56?dchild=1&keywords=laptops&qid=1611094287&sr=8-56']
['https://www.amazon.com//gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_atf_next_aps_sr_pg4_1?ie=UTF8&adId=A00982583SKT9G1E8WEMD&url=%2FHigh-Performance-Ultra-Thin-Entertainment-pre-Installed-Professional%2Fdp%2FB079GQK6BC%2Fref%3Dsr_1_49_sspa%3Fdchild%3D1%26keywords%3Dlaptops%26qid%3D1611094287%26sr%3D8-49-spons%26psc%3D1&qualifier=1611274529&id=2949216330232123&widgetName=sp_atf_next', 'https://www.amazon.com//gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_atf_next_aps_sr_pg4_1?ie=UTF8&adId=A01913892JJI6KO2E97JD&url=%2FStationaryLab-Aluminum-Organizer-Adjustable-Compatible%2Fdp%2FB08P38JJV8%2Fref%3Dsr_1_50_sspa%3Fdchild%3D1%26keywords%3Dlaptops%26qid%3D1611094287%26sr%3D8-50-spons%26psc%3D1&qualifier=1611274529&id=2949216330232123&widgetName=sp_atf_next', 'https://www.amazon.com//HP-Touchscreen-Dual-Core-Processor-14-ds0110nr/dp/B07RX2XV4N/ref=sr_1_51?dchild=1&keywords=laptops&qid=1611094287&sr=8-51', 'https://www.amazon.com//Traditional-Computers-Supports-Expansion-Personal/dp/B08HRVCN8K/ref=sr_1_52?dchild=1&keywords=laptops&qid=1611094287&sr=8-52', 'https://www.amazon.com//HP-Dual-Core-Processor-Bluetooth-Microsoft/dp/B08KLMKLZR/ref=sr_1_53?dchild=1&keywords=laptops&qid=1611094287&sr=8-53', 'https://www.amazon.com//HP-Stream-Laptop-Intel-Renewed/dp/B08LDLRNGF/ref=sr_1_54?dchild=1&keywords=laptops&qid=1611094287&sr=8-54', 'https://www.amazon.com//X3-Air-13-3-inch-180%C2%B0Rotation-Dual-band/dp/B087M2CQG6/ref=sr_1_55?dchild=1&keywords=laptops&qid=1611094287&sr=8-55', 'https://www.amazon.com//HP-i5-10210U-i7-8665U-Keyboard-Graphics/dp/B08QNGWYLJ/ref=sr_1_56?dchild=1&keywords=laptops&qid=1611094287&sr=8-56', 'https://www.amazon.com//HP-Chromebook-Dual-Core-Certified-Refurbished/dp/B07CB2GTH2/ref=sr_1_57?dchild=1&keywords=laptops&qid=1611094287&sr=8-57']
[
```

Comment: your question is how to remove duplicate from list ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Remove duplicates from list

To get rid of duplicates in a `list` you can transform it in a `dict` what would give you unique keys and than transform in `list`again:

```
urls_list = list(dict.fromkeys(urls_list))
```

### Loops

Not sure how you get that number of `urls` from your example, second loop wont make this work, it would only give you 22 urls, cause of its indent.

Take a look of my example, this should make it work and also avoid the fact, that it becomes to duplicates for example from the sponsored links.

**Example**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import numpy as np
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')
pages = np.arange(0,4)

urls_list=[]

for page in pages:
    time.sleep(3)
    page=driver.get('https://www.amazon.com/s?k=laptops&page='+str(page)+'&qid=1611094287&ref=sr_pg_')
    sleep(2)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    
    for a in soup.select('h2 a'):
        base_url='https://www.amazon.com/'
        final_url = base_url+a['href'].replace('https:/','')
        if final_url not in urls_list:
            urls_list.append(final_url)

print(urls_list)
driver.close()
```

Comment: It works. I think I was getting so many URLs because of sponsored links, within the pages. Thanks

Comment: totals of the urls for the range 0-4, is  74  which is right. some sponsored links. Thanks @ HedgeHog

Answer (score 0):

## if you just want to remove duplicate then use set

```
list(set(urllist))
```